# NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy

Am getting following exception stack trace when trying to make a REST

```
org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.lang.Boolean of media type: **application/octet-stream**
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:67)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:448)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:397)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher.invoke(AsynchronousDispatcher.java:253)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:200)
```

I have tried multiple suggestions in other post on stackoverflow and outside including

1. Make sure have jars for 'resteasy-jaxb-provider-3.0.12.Final.jar' and jettison providers
2. Even have either of them rather than both
3. Vary the other jaxrs jar version

Till now what i have been able to conclude:

1. Problem is at the server end rather than the client. The client
   simply receives 500 HTTP error code
2. Server site the request reaches but the response is not getting sent back
3. If you check the error closely, am getting response could not find 'application/octec-stream', even though in the service metadata i have defined 'application/json'. SO somehow am not sure why the application is not able to fetch a json parser

   ```
   @Path("/api/ver1.0/lock")
   public interface LockingService {

       /**
        * Interface method to request a single lock.
        *
        * @param lockRequest
        *            lockRequest
        * @return Boolean
        */
       @POST
       @Path("/request")
       @Consumes("application/json")
       Boolean requestLock(LockRequest lockRequest);
   ```
4. I can make the same code work with everything same except for the version of resteasy jars i.e

**Working**

```
resteasy-jackson-provider-2.3.1.GA.jar
resteasy-jaxb-provider-2.3.1.GA.jar
resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar
resteasy-jettison-provider-2.3.1.GA.jar
resteasy-multipart-provider-2.3.1.GA.jar
resteasy-spring-2.3.1.GA.jar
scannotation-1.0.3.jar
```

**Not Working**

```
resteasy-jackson-provider-3.0.12.Final.jar
resteasy-jaxb-provider-3.0.12.Final.jar
resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.12.Final.jar
resteasy-multipart-provider-3.0.12.Final.jar
resteasy-spring-3.0.12.Final.jar
```

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: You should always add `@Produces` to say what type(s) you can to produce, otherwise if an Accept header is not present, it will likely default to `application/octet-stream`, and how do you expect a boolean to be converted to bytes? This is the cause of the error